# mongoose: findOne where populated entry does not exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm using the following query to find one document:

```
const a = await Entry.findOne({}).populate({
    path: 'myref',
    match: ref => ({
      date: {
        $gte: new Date(ref.timestamp).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0),
        $lt: new Date(ref.timestamp).setHours(23, 59, 59, 9999)
      }
    })
  })
```

It works fine, but now, I want find one entry where populate returns null. Is there any way to do this in mongoose?

Comment: you should use lookup

Comment: by default, Mongoose removes null and undefined values from populated arrays. Use `retainNullValues: true ` option to make populate() retain null and undefined array entries.   https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate